# Limit of $a_n = \sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n}$, with $a,b>0$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a, b>0,$ and define $(a_n)$ to be $a_n=\sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n}$. Find $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n$.

It is obvious that $a_n$ has limit because it is decreasing.

Comment: It has to be between a and b by squeeze theorem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose without losing generality that $a\geq b$. Then I claim that $\lim_{n \to +\infty}a_n = a$. Note that: $$a = \sqrt[n]{a^n} \leq a_n = \sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n} \leq \sqrt[n]{a^n+a^n} = \sqrt[n]{2}a,$$and since $\sqrt[n]{2} \to 1$ as $n\to +\infty$, making $n\to +\infty$ in that chain of inequalities gives $$a \leq \lim_{n \to +\infty}a_n \leq a.$$

Comment: That was nicely done.

Answer (score 1):

Limit of this sequence is equal to $\max (a,b)$.

Answer (score 0):

When $0\neq a\geq b\geq 0$ let $(a^n+b^n)^{1/n} =a (1+(b/a)^n)^{1/n}=a(1+c_n).$

We have $1+(b/a)^n=(1+c_n)^n=\sum_{j=0}^n \binom {n}{j}(c_n)^j\geq 1+ nc_n.\;$ So   $\;2/n \geq  (b/a)^n/n \geq c_n \geq 0.$

Therefore $c_n\to 0.$